# Sitecore Scheduler job automatically stopped running

Tags: sitecore-api, scheduler-job

I have a sitecore scheduler job running every 60 minutes, It used to be every 10 minutes but after testing I changed it to run every 60 minutes

```
<agent type="XYZ.Scheduler.AdviserSync" method="Run" interval="00:60:00"></agent>
```

It worked fine few days but then stopped working, today I chekd in the log files and I found this entry.

```
6032 15:15:19 INFO Scheduler - Skipping inactive agent: XYZ.Scheduler.AdviserSync
```

I also write some log entries when job starts but I can;t find them in log files, looks like job is not running.

Question:

Is interval configured properly? 
Why scheduler job automatically stopped running?
Is there any setting I need to configure to run it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduler - Skypping inactive agent

is generated by **Sitecore.Task.Scheduler.ReadAgents** class

```
private static Scheduler.Agent[] ReadAgents()
{
    Log.Info("Scheduler - Adding agents", typeof(Scheduler));
    try
    {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        XmlNodeList configNodes = Factory.GetConfigNodes("scheduling/agent");
        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in configNodes)
        {
            try
            {
                object obj = Factory.CreateObject(xmlNode, true);
                string @string = StringUtil.GetString(new string[]
                {
                    XmlUtil.GetAttribute("method", xmlNode),
                    "Execute"
                });
                TimeSpan timeSpan = DateUtil.ParseTimeSpan(XmlUtil.GetAttribute("interval", xmlNode), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.0), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string string2 = StringUtil.GetString(new string[]
                {
                    XmlUtil.GetAttribute("name", xmlNode),
                    obj.GetType().FullName
                });
                bool @bool = MainUtil.GetBool(XmlUtil.GetAttribute("async", xmlNode), false);
                if (timeSpan.TotalSeconds > 0.0)
                {
                    Log.Info(string.Concat(new object[]
                    {
                        "Scheduler - Adding agent: ",
                        string2,
                        " (interval: ",
                        timeSpan,
                        ")"
                    }), typeof(Scheduler));
                    Scheduler.Agent value;
                    if (@bool)
                    {
                        value = new Scheduler.AsyncAgent(string2, obj, @string, timeSpan, Scheduler.m_startTime);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        value = new Scheduler.Agent(string2, obj, @string, timeSpan, Scheduler.m_startTime);
                    }
                    arrayList.Add(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Info("Scheduler - Skipping inactive agent: " + string2, typeof(Scheduler));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Log.Error("Error while instantiating agent. Definition: " + xmlNode.OuterXml, exception, typeof(Scheduler));
            }
        }
        Log.Info("Scheduler - Agents added", typeof(Scheduler));
        return arrayList.ToArray(typeof(Scheduler.Agent)) as Scheduler.Agent[];
    }
    catch (Exception exception2)
    {
        Log.Error("Error while reading agents.", exception2, typeof(Scheduler));
    }
    return null;
}
```

On sitecore code it reads the interval and test if the value is not 00:00 :

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateUtil.ParseTimeSpan(XmlUtil.GetAttribute("interval", xmlNode), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.0), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    if (timeSpan.TotalSeconds > 0.0)
            { 
                  // sitecore code
            }
            else
            {
                //if interval is 0 it skips the agent
               Log.Info("Scheduler - Skipping inactive agent: " + string2, typeof(Scheduler));

            }
```

Please have a look to your config files using : **yourhost/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx** and verify the value of interval. I recommend to change the value from **00:60:00** to **00:59:59**

Comment: Probably 00:60:00 is being treated as 0.0 seconds which clearly is not zero, I have changed it to 59:59, I have to wait for an house to see the update.

Comment: I suggest you to change for testing to 00:09:59 .